# Redis server is Restarted For Every two minutes and loses keys for every few minutes

Tags: linux, redis

I am using a 3.2.11 Redis version in ubuntu 16.04. we are writing and reading keys from Redis. After every two minutes, it's getting shut down for the below reason.

signal-handler (1568095246) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...

In windows, the same version and same configuration are working perfectly.

Below are my configurations of Redis-server

"# Server
redis_version:3.2.11
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:c9f2a36594be9567
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 4.15.0-1052-azure x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.9.2
process_id:26959
run_id:f720ccac1536542b7c6ee84172d4c49fca6b80ee
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:78
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
lru_clock:7813869
executable:/usr/bin/redis-server
config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf

## Clients

connected_clients:4
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0

## Memory

used_memory:890304
used_memory_human:869.44K
used_memory_rss:4530176
used_memory_rss_human:4.32M
used_memory_peak:930344
used_memory_peak_human:908.54K
total_system_memory:16796553216
total_system_memory_human:15.64G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:268435456
maxmemory_human:256.00M
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
mem_fragmentation_ratio:5.09
mem_allocator:jemalloc-4.0.3

## Persistence

loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:0
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:0
rdb_last_save_time:1568094879
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:-1
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:-1
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok

## Stats

total_connections_received:11
total_commands_processed:45
instantaneous_ops_per_sec:0
total_net_input_bytes:1645
total_net_output_bytes:3040
instantaneous_input_kbps:0.00
instantaneous_output_kbps:0.00
rejected_connections:0
sync_full:0
sync_partial_ok:0
sync_partial_err:0
expired_keys:0
evicted_keys:0
keyspace_hits:24
keyspace_misses:1
pubsub_channels:0
pubsub_patterns:0
latest_fork_usec:0
migrate_cached_sockets:0

## Replication

role:master
connected_slaves:0
master_repl_offset:0
repl_backlog_active:0
repl_backlog_size:1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset:0
repl_backlog_histlen:0

## CPU

used_cpu_sys:0.07
used_cpu_user:0.03
used_cpu_sys_children:0.00
used_cpu_user_children:0.00

## Cluster

cluster_enabled:0

## Keyspace

db0:keys=31,expires=0,avg_ttl=0

Below are my Redis server logs

```
37507:signal-handler (1568096332) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
37507:M 10 Sep 06:18:52.379 # User requested shutdown...
37507:M 10 Sep 06:18:52.379 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
37507:M 10 Sep 06:18:52.403 * DB saved on disk
37507:M 10 Sep 06:18:52.404 * Removing the pid file.
37507:M 10 Sep 06:18:52.404 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
38199:M 10 Sep 06:18:52.804 * Redis 3.2.11 (00000000/0) 64 bit, standalone mode, port 6379, pid 38199 ready to start.
38199:M 10 Sep 06:18:52.804 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.11
38199:M 10 Sep 06:18:52.804 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
38199:M 10 Sep 06:18:52.805 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
38199:signal-handler (1568096422) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
38199:M 10 Sep 06:20:22.815 # User requested shutdown...
38199:M 10 Sep 06:20:22.815 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
38199:M 10 Sep 06:20:22.836 * DB saved on disk
38199:M 10 Sep 06:20:22.836 * Removing the pid file.
38199:M 10 Sep 06:20:22.836 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
38950:M 10 Sep 06:20:23.333 * Redis 3.2.11 (00000000/0) 64 bit, standalone mode, port 6379, pid 38950 ready to start.
38950:M 10 Sep 06:20:23.335 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.11
38950:M 10 Sep 06:20:23.336 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
38950:M 10 Sep 06:20:23.336 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
38950:signal-handler (1568096513) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
38950:M 10 Sep 06:21:53.409 # User requested shutdown...
38950:M 10 Sep 06:21:53.410 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
38950:M 10 Sep 06:21:53.429 * DB saved on disk
38950:M 10 Sep 06:21:53.429 * Removing the pid file.
38950:M 10 Sep 06:21:53.429 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
39659:M 10 Sep 06:21:53.808 * Redis 3.2.11 (00000000/0) 64 bit, standalone mode, port 6379, pid 39659 ready to start.
39659:M 10 Sep 06:21:53.808 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.11
39659:M 10 Sep 06:21:53.809 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
39659:M 10 Sep 06:21:53.810 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
```

Redis-server Verbose logs

```
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:27.832 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:27.832 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 827584 bytes in use
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:32.844 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:32.844 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 827584 bytes in use
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:37.860 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:37.861 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 827584 bytes in use
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:42.888 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:42.888 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 827584 bytes in use
44263:signal-handler (1568097167) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:47.699 # User requested shutdown...
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:47.700 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:47.718 * DB saved on disk
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:47.718 * Removing the pid file.
44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:47.718 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:48.085 * Redis 3.2.11 (00000000/0) 64 bit, standalone mode, port 6379, pid 44978 ready to start.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:48.085 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.11
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:48.085 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:48.086 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:48.086 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:48.086 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 765984 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:53.097 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:53.097 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 765984 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:58.108 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:58.108 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 765984 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:58.744 - Accepted 10.1.0.11:58060
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:58.744 - Reading from client: Connection reset by peer
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:58.749 - Accepted 10.1.0.10:54662
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:58.750 - Reading from client: Connection reset by peer
44978:M 10 Sep 06:32:59.180 - Accepted 10.1.0.8:53212
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:03.121 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:03.121 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 786856 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:08.132 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:08.132 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 786856 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:13.145 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:13.145 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 786856 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:18.157 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:18.157 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 786856 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:23.168 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:23.168 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 786856 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:28.181 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:28.182 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 786856 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:29.791 - Accepted 10.1.0.10:54812
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:29.791 - Accepted 10.1.0.11:58242
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:29.792 - Reading from client: Connection reset by peer
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:29.792 - Reading from client: Connection reset by peer
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:30.698 - Accepted 10.1.0.7:45992
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:30.814 - Accepted 10.1.0.6:44336
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:33.192 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:33.192 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 828600 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:38.209 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:38.209 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 828600 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:43.221 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:43.221 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 828600 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:48.234 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:48.234 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 828600 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:53.249 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:53.249 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 828600 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:58.261 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:33:58.261 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 828600 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:02.159 - Accepted 10.1.0.10:54950
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:02.160 - Reading from client: Connection reset by peer
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:02.161 - Accepted 10.1.0.11:58420
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:02.161 - Reading from client: Connection reset by peer
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:03.276 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:03.276 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 827576 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:08.292 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:08.292 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 827576 bytes in use
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:13.305 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:13.306 - 3 clients connected (0 slaves), 827576 bytes in use
44978:signal-handler (1568097258) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:18.216 # User requested shutdown...
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:18.216 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:18.247 * DB saved on disk
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:18.247 * Removing the pid file.
44978:M 10 Sep 06:34:18.247 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:18.557 * Redis 3.2.11 (00000000/0) 64 bit, standalone mode, port 6379, pid 45737 ready to start.
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:18.559 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.11
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:18.560 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:18.560 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:18.561 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:18.561 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 766024 bytes in use
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:23.573 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:23.573 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 766024 bytes in use
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:28.588 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:28.589 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 766024 bytes in use
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:33.599 - DB 0: 31 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
45737:M 10 Sep 06:34:33.599 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 766024 bytes in use
```

Sometimes I am facing below error logs in Redis server I am running Redis server as standalone mode

```
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:13.913 * SLAVE OF 192.3.70.16:12220 enabled (user request from 'id=1600 addr=192.3.70.16:42370 fd=9 name= age=0 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=slaveof')
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:14.880 * Connecting to MASTER 192.3.70.16:12220
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:14.881 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:15.092 # Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:15.883 * Connecting to MASTER 192.3.70.16:12220
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:15.883 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:16.093 # Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:16.886 * Connecting to MASTER 192.3.70.16:12220
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:16.886 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:17.093 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:17.300 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:17.714 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:17.926 * Full resync from master: ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ:0
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:17.926 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: receiving 3372687 bytes from master
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:19.400 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Flushing old data
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:19.400 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Loading DB in memory
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:19.400 # Wrong signature trying to load DB from file
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:19.400 # Failed trying to load the MASTER synchronization DB from disk
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:19.892 * Connecting to MASTER 192.3.70.16:12220
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:19.892 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:20.100 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
104680:M 11 Sep 10:05:21.184 * MASTER MODE enabled (user request from 'id=1600 addr=192.3.70.16:42370 fd=9 name= age=8 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=slaveof')
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:22.073 * SLAVE OF 192.3.70.16:51622 enabled (user request from 'id=1605 addr=192.3.70.16:42508 fd=9 name= age=0 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=slaveof')
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:22.906 * Connecting to MASTER 192.3.70.16:51622
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:22.906 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
104680:S 11 Sep 10:05:23.117 # Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
```

Comment: What do your Redis Logs say ? The location of the Log file can be found out at /etc/redis/redis.conf file

Comment: Your best bet is to reinstall the Redis server OR change the Log levels to verbose and see. There is nothing in the above log.

Comment: I changed the log level to verbose and updated the logs, please check

Comment: Every time it recieves a SigTerm signal it would create a bug logfile. Can you search for these files in your Logs directory. Post the content of one of such file. It seems one of your binary is not compatible causing it to crash & handle termination gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error and now i suspect command: *SLAVE OF 192.3.70.16:12220 enabled (user request from 'id=1600 addr=192.3.70.16:42370 fd=9 name= age=0 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=slaveof')*

Please, check who send this command to your redis server? Try set: protected-mode yes (redis.cfg) and config connecting password for your redis server

Comment: I have monitored this From the past two weeks. There is no data loss & auto-restart also not happening.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem and it was a permission problem. Check your Redis,  so it has all the required permissions to all the directory it needs.

Answer (score 0):

The log say : 44263:M 10 Sep 06:32:47.699 # User requested shutdown...
try to reinstall

Comment: I re-installed the Redis server and again I am facing the same issue below are my logs    
along with the above error, I am getting below one as well                             Reading from the client: Connection reset by peer      FROM ALL CLIENTS

Comment: I got this error and Keys got delete                                                                             Failed opening the RDB file root (in server root dir /var/spool/cron) for saving: Read-only file system

Comment: Failed opening the RDB file dump.rdb (in server root dir /etc/cron.d) for saving: Read-only file system

Comment: Are u delete wrong file.  /etc/cron.d is timed task file.

Comment: It's beyond my reach

Comment: I was starting Redis as a service but now I started as init.d scripts and I am using private IP and port from application to connect Redis. I monitored last night. Data loss was not there. Because of public IP and port I am facing the issue ?